# Turf js drawing perfect square with center point and radius

Tags: javascript, geojson, turfjs

I am trying to generate p square polygon out of center point and radius. Like below.

```
bboxPolygon(square(bbox(circle(_circle.center, 0.5, { steps: 64 }))))
```

All the function is from the turf.js

I believe that should generate perfect square or at least close to square. However, it returns  rectangular.

I am not sure this is turf library problem or I am using it wrong.

**circle geojson**

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -73.93524199999999,
          40.734656941636764
        ],
        [
          -73.93791238162646,
          40.73411472349626
        ],
        [
          -73.93986713367875,
          40.73263337851494
        ],
        [
          -73.94058248193825,
          40.730609876934174
        ],
        [
          -73.93986685239045,
          40.72858643688632
        ],
        [
          -73.93791210033818,
          40.72710521497083
        ],
        [
          -73.93524199999999,
          40.72656305836324
        ],
        [
          -73.93257189966181,
          40.72710521497083
        ],
        [
          -73.93061714760952,
          40.72858643688632
        ],
        [
          -73.92990151806174,
          40.730609876934174
        ],
        [
          -73.93061686632124,
          40.73263337851494
        ],
        [
          -73.93257161837353,
          40.73411472349626
        ],
        [
          -73.93524199999999,
          40.734656941636764
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

bboxPolygon result

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "bbox": [
    -73.93928894163675,
    40.72656305836324,
    -73.93119505836323,
    40.734656941636764
  ],
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -73.93928894163675,
          40.72656305836324
        ],
        [
          -73.93119505836323,
          40.72656305836324
        ],
        [
          -73.93119505836323,
          40.734656941636764
        ],
        [
          -73.93928894163675,
          40.734656941636764
        ],
        [
          -73.93928894163675,
          40.72656305836324
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `turf.square` function. It is not doing what I would expect.

You should get something quite close to a square if you replace
`bboxPolygon(square(bbox(circle(_circle.center, 0.5, { steps: 64 }))))`

with

`bboxPolygon(bbox(circle(_circle.center, 0.5, { steps: 64 })))`

Here is an example of what the outputs looks like. *red* is the circle, *green* is the output you get from using square and *blue* is the output of not using square.

[image]

If you look into [the source code](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-square/index.js) of `square` you will notice that it actually does not create a bbox which has equal distances on each side. However it creates a bbox which has equal change in degree. Since we are working in longitude and latitude, that will usually NOT be a polygon which is square in distance.

I am unsure why anyone would ever need this `square` function since i would find it way more usefull if it was square in distance, however I do not know if this is the intended behaviour.

**TLDR**
Try `bboxPolygon(bbox(circle(_circle.center, 0.5, { steps: 64 })))` instead

Answer (score 2):

The above answer by @the_cheff is highly inefficient, because it iterates over 64 points to compute a rectangle. An alternative solution would be an implementation similar to how Turf implements a [turf-circle](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-circle/index.ts):

```
const square = (center: [number, number], radius: number): GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Geometry> => {
   const cross = Math.sqrt(2 * radius ** 2);
   const coordinates = [];
   
   for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    coordinates.push(destination(center, cross, i * -360 / 4 + 45, {}).geometry.coordinates);
   }
   coordinates.push(coordinates[0]);

   return polygon([coordinates], {});
}
```

Hope this helps anybody in the future.